# getDayOfMonth throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get the selected date in a dialog but unfortunately I got NullPointerException.

```
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add, null));
            builder.setTitle("Add new event");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.ad_date_picker);
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DAY, datepicker.getDayOfMonth());
                    values.put(DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH, datepicker.getMonth());
                    values.put(DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_YEAR, datepicker.getYear());

                    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    db.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
```

Stack trace:

```
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at com.dennis.countdown.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5193)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-02 17:34:31.890: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The DatePicker is in the XML file because I need a custom dialog with title field and a date picker. I didn't find any other way to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:background="#FFFFBB33"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Title" />
<DatePicker 
    android:id="@+id/ad_date_picker"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One of `R`, `R.id`, or `datepicker` must be null. So which line is 38?

Comment: Have you set any values to the DatePicker on xml?

Comment: @Dennis I mean which line of code is line 38? The one from the stack trace. Otherwise we're just guessing at what is throwing the exception. The exception is clearly your from code, so it's going to be something with a `.` member accessor.

Comment: @lc. Line 38 is: ``values.put(DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_DAY, datepicker.getDayOfMonth());`` @IronBlossom I posted the xml file above.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, so probably `datepicker` is null (`DbHelper` is a static class, not an instance so it should never be null)...you can work backwards from there

Comment: It's an xml thing so clean project then run.. And check

Comment: Initialize your DatePicker outside the builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Your DatePicker is null`, When you try to access datepicker.getDayOfMonth(), it throws `NPE`
You need to initialize your DatePicker in onCreate

```
  DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.ad_date_picker);
```

if your date picker is there in inflatted view than get it from the inflatted view

```
 DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) inflattedview.findViewById(R.id.ad_date_picker);
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved with help of [Pragnani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176848/1866009).

Instead of:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add, null));
DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.ad_date_picker);
```

I used:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_add, null);
builder.setView(view);
DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_date_picker);
```